# How to specify a launch image for Android app

Tags: android, launch, splash-screen

Right now my application zooms into a white screen as it is launching.

I have noticed Google default Android apps using a launch image while their app binaries load.

Does Android offer the ability to use a launch image for an application?
I do not mean a splash screen that is on a timer AFTER the app has launched. I mean a static resource that is shown while the app is loading. Like the [Apple launch image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).
Thanks.

Example of launch image for iOS [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/).
[image: Apple]

Comment: your question is not about ios

Answer (score 4):

This guide on splash screens might be useful for you:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

This will show a splash screen in the small amount of time before the app is initialized.  If you do not feel like clicking:

The code sample is available here:

https://github.com/cstew/Splash

Comment: OP said, not using any timer. LaunchImage is a static screen offered by ios. Android does not have any option like this.

Comment: Isn't this just a splash screen that is loaded AFTER the app binary? I would like a launch image solution that is shown while the app is loading starting at the app icon click.

Comment: @AnsonL This tutorial (and code) show that when you click the app icon, a "Splash Screen Activity" is shown with a static image resource, then the main activity is loaded. How is that not what you want?

Comment: This is what Google uses when launching apps like YouTube.  It is so you do not look at an empty screen while all the resources are being loaded.  This should resolve what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Having development experience on both sides, No, android does not provide any such way similar to LaunchImage of ios.